# C programming: How can I check if given number is exactly for digits, no more / no less?

Tags: c

C programming: How can I check if given number is exactly for digits, no more / no less?

I'm still new to C programming. Sorry if that's an easy question to ask.

Comment: I assume you mean _four_ (4) digits?

Comment: When you say ‘for’, do you mean *four*? In that case `number >= 1000 && number < 10000` (assuming decimal).

Comment: read it using `fgets()` and find the length using `strlen()`. If needed later as a number, use `sprintf()`.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I assume 'for' = 'four' ... so 10000 < number < 999

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_log10.htm

Comment: @jabujavi That's not quite right… Neither syntactically nor semantically.

Comment: Do you count leading zeros, too?

Comment: @Biffen without anymore info neither code...

Comment: @jabujavi Firstly, you can't do two comparisons at once like that. Secondly, you're doing it the wrong way around (which number is larger than 10,000 *and* smaller than 999?).

Comment: hahaha sorry I dismissed it... but I just writting the concept...

Answer (score 2):

just check the range of the number:

```
int x = 4125; //this is just an example value ...
if( (x >= 1000 && x <= 9999) || (x >= -9999 && x <= -1000) ){
    //is valid
}else{
    //is not valid
}
```

Comment: what if it is a -ve number?

Comment: you're right, haven't thought about that. but you simply could add an "||" to the if, to check the negative spectrum as well

Comment: What if it's a double?

Comment: @MartinJames: then the question should have been more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

here's a function that does that

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int n);

int main(void)
{
    int n = 1234;
    int num_of_digits = f(n);
    if( num_of_digits == 4 )
    {
        printf("%d\n",num_of_digits);
    }
}

int f(int n)
{
    int num_of_digits = 0;
    while( n )
    {
        n /= 10;
        num_of_digits++;
    }
    return num_of_digits;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you really want 4 digits you can use the approach given by Tom Mekken.
But if you just want to check the number of digits of a integer you can always use this approach:

```
floor (log10 (abs (x))) + 1
```

Remember that it wont work when the number is zero so you'll have to check it before.

Comment: Corner case problems: `x == 0`,  `x == INT_MIN`.